# Antenna coil resonant for 134.2KHz

Tags: antenna, rfid

What would be the best N turns, when building a simple layer antenna coil to be resonant to 134.2kHz?
Based on this specifications:
1mm insulated copper wire.
4.5cm diameter.
Minimum length (based on 1mm insulated wire with N turns).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not that it will make much difference in practice, but is it 124.3 or 134.2?

Comment: Sorry I messed up in the title, I mean 134.2kHz from the RFID specifications

Answer (score 4):

You cannot make a resonant antenna for such low frequencies with those dimensions. Just try to calculate the wavelength for that frequency.

What is normally done (e.g. for RFID applications) is a RLC circuit that resonates at that frequency. The inductance L and part of R come from the coil; C and the rest of R are added components. Energy for transmission is normally provided by switching a transistor at that frequency. Be careful of the high voltages involved.

Comment: Can you provide an example for this frecuency? In fact, this is for an RFID application